# Adding button to select between different characters

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to perform something that I can choose between different characters. I don't find any idea how to perform this. I have already made the button. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have tried to add button when you click then it open menu where are different characters but i don't have idea how i can perform that i can choose it and use it.

Comment: **Menu** which menu are you talking about?

Comment: I think that i mean Switch Statement and Char. So i finally found some ideas on the internet.